# Excel VBA: click on a checkbox that has a label and no name

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, label

I'm trying to automate a process, and one of the tasks is to click on a checkbox located on a website. This is the only code I can find that is related to this specific checkbox:

```
<label class="chbx" for="RiverFlood_MapServer"></label>
```

On this website when you first load it, there are dropdowns that are closed. You have to open them to click this box. I'm not sure if this is partially why I can't get this work.

This is what I have written to do this specific portion of the task.

```
Dim Login As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set Login = IE.document
```

There is some other stuff in here that's already completed, like logging on automatically. At this point it has also already navigated to the page.

```vb
Dim layer As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim layers As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set layers = Login.getElementsByTagName("chbx")

For Each layer In layers

    If layer.Label = "RiverFlood_MapServer" Then
        layer.Click                
    Else
    End If

Next layer
```